# Java - object cannot be resolved (to a variable)

Tags: java, object, constructor

At first sorry if not everything is understandable (I'm from Germany). And please try to understand that I'm quite new to java and may have done some stupid mistakes. I have two classes. One with the constructor and functions and one with the menu.

Class 1 (constructor and functions):

```
public class Matrix {
    private float[][] matrix;
...
    public void createMatrix(int zei, int spa){
...
    public void printMatrix(){
        int x = 0;
        while (x < this.matrix.length){
            for (float elem : this.matrix[x]){
                System.out.printf("%10d", elem); 
            }
            x++;
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Class 2 (Menu):

```
public class MenuMatrix{
    public static void menue(){
...
        if (m1 == null){
            Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
            m1.createMatrix(zei, spa);
        }
        else if (m2 == null){
            Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
            m2.createMatrix(zei, spa);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Which matrix do you want to replace?");
            m1.printMatrix();
            m2.printMatrix();
            int x = readInteger("Please choose matrix (1) or (2).");
...
```

I wanted to make sure that only 2 objects of this kind could exist. Therefore I've included the check if the object already exist (m1/m2 == null). There is the first error. In the line with the if-clauses it tells me that "m1/m2 cannot be resolved to a variable". The other error comes in the m1/m2.printMatrix() line. Eclipse says "m1/m2 cannot be resolved".
Informations on a few different sites have told me that it should work this way. I hope you can tell me where exactly the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Java variable scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e6906). In your case, its not even scope, you haven't even declared the `m1`

Comment: its nothing to do with scope, his variables are referenced before they are declared

Comment: Where do you declare m1/m2? They don't exist yet.

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please, post a complete version cause something can be misinterpred at our eyes. Anyway, from what I see, you're checking m1 and m2 without respecting the declaration scopes: you declare and init them into the IF..THEN..ELSE, but you try to check them into the IF statement. Is that what you wanted to achieve? If yes, you should change the scope of your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code sample:

```
if (m1 == null){
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
    m1.createMatrix(zei, spa);
}
else if (m2 == null){
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
    m2.createMatrix(zei, spa);
}
```

Notice that the `Matrix m1` and `m2` variables are declared *after* the first reference to them is made. Those declarations are also within the scope of the `if` block, which will cause them to be discarded as soon as the flow of execution exits the block and continues outside.

In other words, when the parser reaches the `if (m1 == null)` checks, it notices that the variables by the names of `m1` and `m2` do not exist yet.

You'll need to move the declarations outside of the body of the `if` statements so that you make sure they exist *before* you try to use them within a given scope. A quick search should provide good info on variable scoping rules for any language.

One possible way here is to turn your variables into private members of the `MatrixMenu` class, like so:

```
public class MatrixMenu {
    private Matrix m1;
    private Matrix m2;
    // ...
    if (m1 == null){
        m1 = new Matrix();
        m1.createMatrix(zei, spa);
    }
    else if (m2 == null){
        m2 = new Matrix();
        m2.createMatrix(zei, spa);
    }
    // ...
```

That's one possible way to solve your problem.

PS: Another point is that you should consider removing the `createMatrix` method and instead pass those arguments to the `Matrix` constructor to produce a valid/initialized matrix instance as soon as `new` returns. In other words:

```
public class Matrix {
    private float[][] values;
    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        // throw exception if any argument is <= 0

        values = new float[rows][columns];
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: @berl1n Please don't forget to accept the answer that you find most helpful in solving your problem. That's how we say 'thank you' around here and lets everyone else know that your question has a solution :)

Comment: Yep. I just needed to check a few things. It's still not working as expected but it may work after changing a few other things :)

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing those variables before they are declared.

Comment: I know that but the other sites have said that it should work this way. I want to check if they already exist. If I declare them before I check this it wouldn't work I guess as they are now existing. Or am I wrong in my thoughts?

Comment: Either you are misunderstand what they wrote, or they are just wrong. It will never work like that, ever.